# How to put a * in a criteria of the FILTER function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to apply a `*` in a criteria of the FILTER function, however, Excel is returning `#CALC`.

My formula is :

```
IF($C$347="No";UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!$N:$N;((Sheet2!$I:$I="1_1_*_1_0")+(Sheet2!$I:$I="1_1_*_2_0")+(Sheet2!$I:$I="1_1_*_3_0")+(Sheet2!$I:$I="1_1_*_4_0"))));...)
```

Indeed, the `*` can contains different char and I don't want to put all possibilities in the formula ...

Can you please help me to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: Use `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` which allows wild cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ISNUMBER(SEARCH()):

```
FILTER(Sheet2!$N:$N;((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1_1_*_1_0";Sheet2!$I:$I)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1_1_*_2_0";Sheet2!$I:$I)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1_3_*_1_0";Sheet2!$I:$I)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1_4_*_1_0";Sheet2!$I:$I))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this, I would say it isn't possible.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/can-i-use-wildcards-with-the-new-filter-function/m-p/1179560

Link authors workaround that did what he wanted:
`=FILTER($A$2:$A$8,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1,$A$2:$A$8,1)))`

I believe he got it from the sample worksheet that a different poster attached to a response.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon.  Please apply what that link says to the question and post how it answers this specific question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That's fair. However, I didn't want to repost that entire thread. OP would need to read it and follow the suggested work arounds.

Comment: Ah, didn't think to post it as link in a comment. I'm new to this question answering :)